# Creating RAID arrays on files instead of block devices

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, block-device

Is it possible to create a RAID array on files for testing purposes?

Suppose I want to create a level-1 RAID and I don't have for example 10 block devices to do that but instead I want to simulate that using files instead of block devices.

What I've done so far is this:

```
fallocate -l 1M disk1
fallocate -l 1M disk2
mkfs.ext4 disk1
mkfs.ext4 disk2
sudo mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 ./disk1 ./disk2
```

But after that I get the error :

```
mdadm: ./disk1 is not a block device.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes you can. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545618/100397 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474877/100397 for worked examples.

Comment: Don't `mkfs` the raid components! The filesystem belongs on top of the RAID array, not below it, so `mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0` afterwards. Creating a filesystem on the components is useless at best and may confuse some tools.

Comment: @TooTea What do you mean by ```The filesystem belongs on top of the RAID array```? Does RAID acts as a layer between the filesystems and the disks like what for example what **device mapper** does?

Comment: Yes, RAID will turn a bunch of block devices (disks) into a single block device (something that looks just like a disk, but is bigger/faster/more reliable). You then just put a filesystem on top of this "fancy disk".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the loop device. It makes files appears as devices like `/dev/loop0` etc. They can then be mounted as filesystems, and should work with md. From the man page `loop(4)`:

> The loop device is a block device that maps its data blocks not to a
> physical device such as a hard disk or optical disk drive, but to the
> blocks of a regular file in a filesystem or to another block device.

See e.g.

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html

For testing things that need block devices, LVM might also be useful. It lets you make multiple logical volumes from a single physical partition (or the other way around) and destroying/recreating/resizing the volumes is also much simpler than with disk partitions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it. Just create a loop device from the file and use that device to create the array:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=mydev count=80 bs=1M
$ sudo losetup -f mydev
```

You will have an 80M device ready and you can use it in any context where you would use a block device.

```
$ sudo losetup -l
```

Will tell you the current mapping.

Comment: I think the `-l` option doesn't need root access.

Comment: Good point. In Debian though you don't need to be root **but** the executable lives in `/sbin`, which is not in users' PATH by default. So, I would need to write `/sbin/losetup -l` which might or not work with other distributions, depending on where the binary was installed. With your comment, visitors will know it is not needed, thanks.